# how to load assemblies on runtime with dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a daemon for preloading assembly or launching new executable assembly.

To preload a assembly:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
```

To launch dll:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssembly(executablePath, args);
```

but I can't find LoadFile or AppDomain class in netcoreapp1.0 API.

how to port it for dotnet core?

---

I was try to use LoadFromAssemblyPath and AssemblyLoadContext.
but it makes exceptions on runtime.

here is code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

namespace Tizen.DotnetLauncher
{
    class Shield
    {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (args.Length < 1) return;

        var asl = new AssemblyLoader();
        string fpath = Path.GetFullPath(args[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(fpath);
        var asm = asl.LoadFromAssemblyPath(fpath);

        Type[] types = null;

        try
        {
            types = asm.GetTypes();
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
        {
            foreach (Exception ex in e.LoaderExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        foreach (Type info in types)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(info.GetTypeInfo());
        }
    }

    class AssemblyLoader : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

LoaderExceptions output:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the specified file.
File name: 'System.Runtime'
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingEvent(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingResolvingEvent(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
```

exceptions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load assemblies located in a folder in .net core console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895278/how-to-load-assemblies-located-in-a-folder-in-net-core-console-app)