# How to dynamically load assemblies in dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm building a web application, where I would like separate concerns, i.e. having abstractions and implementations in different projects.

To achieve this, I've tried to implement a composition root concept, where all implementation must have an instance of `ICompositionRootComposer` to register services, types etc.

```
public interface ICompositionRootComposer
{
    void Compose(ICompositionConfigurator configurator);
}
```

In projects that are referred directly in the build hierarchy, implementations of `ICompositionRootComposer` are called, and services are registered correct in the underlying IoC container.

The problem arises when I'm trying to register services in a project, where I've set up a post build task that copies the built dll to the web project's debug folder:

```
cp -R $(TargetDir)"assembly and symbol name"* $(SolutionDir)src/"webproject path"/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1
```

I'm loading the assembly with: (Inspiration: [How to load assemblies located in a folder in .net core console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895278/how-to-load-assemblies-located-in-a-folder-in-net-core-console-app))

```
internal class AssemblyLoader : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    private string folderPath;

    internal AssemblyLoader(string folderPath)
    {
        this.folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(folderPath);
    }

    internal Assembly Load(string filePath)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(fileInfo.Name.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, string.Empty));

        return this.Load(assemblyName);
    }

    protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        var dependencyContext = DependencyContext.Default;
        var ressource = dependencyContext.CompileLibraries.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name.Contains(assemblyName.Name));

        if(ressource != null)
        {
            return Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(ressource.Name));
        }

        var fileInfo = this.LoadFileInfo(assemblyName.Name);
        if(File.Exists(fileInfo.FullName))
        {
            Assembly assembly = null;
            if(this.TryGetAssemblyFromAssemblyName(assemblyName, out assembly))
            {
                return assembly;
            }
            return this.LoadFromAssemblyPath(fileInfo.FullName);
        }

        return Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
    }

    private FileInfo LoadFileInfo(string assemblyName)
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(this.folderPath, $"{assemblyName}.dll");

        return new FileInfo(fullPath);
    }

    private bool TryGetAssemblyFromAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyName, out Assembly assembly)
    {
        try
        {
            assembly = Default.LoadFromAssemblyName(assemblyName);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            assembly = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

With this I'm able to load the assembly and call the projects `ICompositionRootComposer` implementation.

But the problem is that it doesn't seem to recognize any of my types.

When calling my configurator with

```
configurator.RegisterTransiantService<IFoo, Foo>();
```

it should register IFoo and Foo in the IoC.
But when debugging I'm not able to get info of the types, i.e via typeof(Foo) in the debug console in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I found this source code useful: https://github.com/dheerajawale-svg/dynamic-dependency-loader.
maybe it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

It turned out, that I had the property `PreserveCompilationContext` set to true, and that's why the debugger wouldn't register my manually copied assembly.
When I removed the property from the web project csproj file, everything worked.

Answer (score 14):

Necromancing.

---

You can create a wrapper class for the old `Assembly.LoadFile` to do that.

This has the added benefit that you can stay backward-compatible with `dotnet-none-core` by applying search-and-replace changes in old code-bases.

```
namespace System.Reflection
{
    public class Assembly2
    {
        public static System.Reflection.Assembly LoadFile(string path)
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = null;
            
#if NET_CORE
            // Requires nuget - System.Runtime.Loader
            assembly = System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(path);
#else
            assembly = System.Reflection. Assembly.LoadFile(path);
#endif 
            return assembly;
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>*You'll need to add `System.Runtime.Loader` via NuGet.*</sub>

Comment: I actually ended up hooking up to `AssemblyLoadContext.Resolving` event to help the load context to load the assemblies it was unable to load itself.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware that ASP.NET Core has it's own, built-in [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) mechanism? It can be easily switched to other IoC container for your needs, I don't think that you need to reinvent it.

What you need to do here is use a reflection to make a generic method and call after that, something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var myAssembly = LoadAssembly();
    // find first interface
    var firstInterfaceType = myAssembly.DefinedTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsInterface).GetType();
    // find it's implementation
    var firstInterfaceImplementationType = myAssembly.DefinedTypes.Where(t => t.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(firstInterfaceType)).GetType();

    // get general method info
    MethodInfo method = typeof(IServiceCollection).GetMethod("AddTransient");
    // provide types to generic method
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(firstInterfaceType, firstInterfaceImplementationType);
    // register your types
    generic.Invoke(services, null);
}
```

Comment: I'm Award of the .net core DI mechanism, but I would like to keep the registration of implementations in the project, where the code is placed. Your approach seems to maintain a hard coupling to the external project from the web project.

Comment: `ConfigureService` is a composition root for the dependency injection in the ASP.NET. You may use the same approach in your self-implemented root

Comment: I'm still NOT convinced - and regardless, I think we've gone a bit off-topic. I asked why the types in my copied project couldn't be loaded, even though I can debug as far as my composer in the same project.

Comment: As I said, you may use the same approach in your own code. Did you try that?