# Dynamically create an instance of a type from an assembly that is already referenced (but never accessed)

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-core, .net-assembly

Using .net core console app

I have an assembly `runner.exe` that has a reference to `functions.dll`. Inside `functions.dll` there's a class called `Functions.MyLibary`

From `runner.exe` I want to create an instance of `Functions.MyLibary` (using the qualified string name)

I've already tried [How to dynamically load assemblies in dotnet core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353999/how-to-dynamically-load-assemblies-in-dotnet-core). This unfortunately only works if the assembly `functions.dll` is **not** referenced.

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()` also doesn't contain informations about `functions.dll`. (If I don't use any classes from `functions.dll`)

Any clue an how to solve the issue?

*In runner.exe*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // functions.dll is not there.. unless the next line gets uncommented
    var assemblies = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();  

    //var dummy = new Functions.MyLibrary(); 

    // This only works is the assembly is not referenced. 
    var a  = System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext
                .Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"PATH\functions.dll");
}
```

*In functions.dll*

```
public class MyLibrary
{
    public void Foo()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @L.B there's not really much to code ... but will add it...

Comment: Try to access to that assembly (for ex,`var type = typeof(ClassLibrary1.MyLibrary);`) before calling *GetReferencedAssemblies*

Comment: Why do you think that the linked question only works for not referenced assemblies? References are mostly a *compile-time* concept, and so there shouldn't be much at *runtime* to distinguish between assemblies you referenced and those you did not.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever indeed I was expecting the same behaviour like in the in the .net framework world. I just did a test out of couriousity and when the assembly is referenced I can't load it.