# .NET Core Assembly.LoadFile at PostBuild event

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need generate `typescript` files from some of my C# classes after build.

I created `dotnet cli tool` and added post-build event

```
dotnet tsgenerator "$(TargetPath)"
```

where `$(TargetPath)` is macros pointing, for example, `D:\Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\my.dll`

Next, i tried to load assembly next way:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dllPath = args[0]; // "D:\Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\my.dll"
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
    var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes(); // Throws exception
}
```

But i got `ReflectionTypeLoadException` that says `Could not load file or assembly` for some references assemblies (for example, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery`).

How i can load assembly for .NET Core applications?

Comment: what is `dllPath`?

Comment: @DanielA.White parameter from MSBuild `$(TargetPath)`

Comment: how is that getting set?

Comment: @DanielA.White project settings -> Build Events -> Post-Build event: `dotnet tsgenerator "$(TargetPath)"`

Comment: in the c#......

Comment: @DanielA.White edited question. Now better code example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm found solution at [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11639). Message by [amits1995](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11639#issuecomment-314100566) and [angelcalvasp](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11639#issuecomment-363441773).

I'm added `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` to my csproj and using this code to load assembly:

```
public static class AssemblyLoader
{
    public static Assembly LoadFromAssemblyPath(string assemblyFullPath)
    {
        var fileNameWithOutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assemblyFullPath);
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(assemblyFullPath);
        var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyFullPath);

        var inCompileLibraries = DependencyContext.Default.CompileLibraries.Any(l => l.Name.Equals(fileNameWithOutExtension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        var inRuntimeLibraries = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries.Any(l => l.Name.Equals(fileNameWithOutExtension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        var assembly = (inCompileLibraries || inRuntimeLibraries)
            ? Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(fileNameWithOutExtension))
            : AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyFullPath);

        if (assembly != null)
            LoadReferencedAssemblies(assembly, fileName, directory);

        return assembly;
    }

    private static void LoadReferencedAssemblies(Assembly assembly, string fileName, string directory)
    {
        var filesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Where(x => x != fileName).Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)).ToList();
        var references = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

        foreach (var reference in references)
        {
            if (filesInDirectory.Contains(reference.Name))
            {
                var loadFileName = reference.Name + ".dll";
                var path = Path.Combine(directory, loadFileName);
                var loadedAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(path);
                if (loadedAssembly != null)
                    LoadReferencedAssemblies(loadedAssembly, loadFileName, directory);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dllPath = args[0]; // "D:\Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\my.dll"
    var assembly = AssemblyLoader.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dllPath);
    var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes(); // No exceptions
}
```

Comment: my answer has same approach!

Comment: @Prateek in my case your solution throws `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'` at `var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(res.First().Name));` called from `var deped = asl.CallForDependency(asm.GetName());`. Code from github issue has no exceptions and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are able to load assembly but `GetTypes()` and `GetExportedTypes()` depend on the public classes within that assembly, if they have external references you get this exception.

**Answer:**
*This means the `Types` of that assembly depend on other assembly which the current .NetCore does not have access at the run time because it can not connect to other dependent assemblies*

**Solution:**
Get dependencies of the DLL assemblies and compile all of them, then load each assembly iteratively to get all ExportedTypes (i.e publicly visible Types)

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel;// add this nuget

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var asl = new AssemblyLoader();
        var asm = asl.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"C:\temp\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll");
        try
        {

            var y = asm.GetExportedTypes();
            Console.WriteLine(y);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got exception at first attempt of GetExportedTypes ");
            Console.WriteLine("\t*********" + e1.Message + "**************");

            var deped = asl.CallForDependency(asm.GetName());

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + deped.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("----------All Exported Types------------");

                foreach (var item in deped.ExportedTypes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Got exception at second attempt of GetExportedTypes ");
                Console.WriteLine("\t*********" + e2.Message + "**************");
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

public class AssemblyLoader :AssemblyLoadContext
{
    protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        var deps = DependencyContext.Default;
        var res = deps.CompileLibraries.Where(d => d.Name.Contains(assemblyName.Name)).ToList();
        var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(res.First().Name));
        return assembly;
    }

    public Assembly CallForDependency(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        return this.Load(assemblyName);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Got exception at first attempt of GetExportedTypes
        *********Could not load file or assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. An operation is not legal in the current state. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131509)**************

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
----------All Exported Types------------
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AntiforgeryServiceCollectionExtensions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryOptions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryTokenSet
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgeryAdditionalDataProvider
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.AntiforgeryFeature
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.AntiforgeryOptionsSetup
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.AntiforgerySerializationContext
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.AntiforgerySerializationContextPooledObjectPolicy
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.AntiforgeryToken
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.BinaryBlob
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.CryptographyAlgorithms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryAdditionalDataProvider
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenGenerator
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenStore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultClaimUidExtractor
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.IAntiforgeryFeature
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.IAntiforgeryTokenGenerator
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.IAntiforgeryTokenSerializer
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.IAntiforgeryTokenStore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.IClaimUidExtractor
```

**Reference and explanation on ReflectionTypeLoadException:**
[Assembly.GetTypes Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> **ReflectionTypeLoadException**
>
> The assembly contains one or more types that cannot be loaded. The
>   array returned by the `Types` property of this exception contains a Type
>   object for each type that was loaded and null for each type that could
>   not be loaded, while the `LoaderExceptions` property contains an
>   exception for each type that could not be loaded.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The returned array includes nested types.
>
> If the `GetTypes` method is called on an assembly and a type in that
>   assembly is dependent on a type in an assembly that has not been
>   loaded (for example, if it derives from a type in the second
>   assembly), a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` is thrown. For example, this
>   can happen if the first assembly was loaded with the
>   `ReflectionOnlyLoad` or `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` methods, and the second
>   assembly was not loaded. It can also happen with assemblies loaded
>   using the Load and `LoadFile` methods if the second assembly cannot be
>   located when the `GetTypes` method is called.
>
> ***Note***
>
> If a type has been forwarded to another assembly, it is not included
>   in the returned array. For information on type forwarding, see Type
>   Forwarding in the `Common Language Runtime`.

**Linked :**

- [How to load assemblies located in a folder in .net core console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895278/how-to-load-assemblies-located-in-a-folder-in-net-core-console-app#40521330)
- [How to dynamically load assemblies in dotnet core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353999/how-to-dynamically-load-assemblies-in-dotnet-core?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try the LoadFrom method for loading in the assembly, rather than LoadFile:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dllPath = args[0]; // "D:\Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\my.dll"
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
    var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes(); // Throws exception
}
```

You will also need to add the same references that are in the ddl file to your current project, so that the types are defined.

Comment: This is a MVC project with nuget dependencies. `Assembly.LoadFrom` gives same error: `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find file specified.` And many similar errors for all referenced via nuget assemblies