# .net core 1.1: Type.GetType from external assembly returns null

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly

I'm porting a console app to .NET core which load types from external libraries. In full .NET Framework using `Type.GetType("typename, assemblyname")` works when the assembly is located in the same folder that executable.

In .NET Core, it returns null, wherever I place the library.

As a workaround I've installed the `System.Runtime.Loader` package and attached to `Resolving` event to force the loading from a full path:

```
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += Default_Resolving;
type = Type.GetType(value);
```

where delegate is:

```
private static Assembly Default_Resolving(AssemblyLoadContext context, AssemblyName assembly)
{
    return context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1",  $"{assembly.Name}.dll"));
}
```

The question is: where does .NET core looks for when loading an external assembly?

Comment: You're question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895278/how-to-load-assemblies-located-in-a-folder-in-net-core-console-app

Comment: Yes, I've readed through that question before, but what I would like to learn is: if I don't use System.Runtime.Loader package at all, just the line Type.GetType, where does .NET looks for the assembly?

Comment: @Farlop: I think you are asking two separate questions - figuring out why your call didn't work and how .net core locates assemblies. it may make sense to ask the latter in a different question. But I for the that I can point you to this document: https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/corehost.md

Comment: Thank you for the link @MartinUllrich, now I see that 'Any file with the suffix .dll in the same folder as the managed application being loaded (the "Application Base") will be considered a viable assembly during the resolution process'.... so... well... I don't understand why is not working, when I'm copying the .dll files in the same folder where the application is ('bin\debug')

Answer (score 3):

This took me ages to work out. Dynamic loads only happen from the execution directory by default. Static loads are quite capable of walking into your nuget package cache (this is what .runtimeconfig.json and .deps.json are for), but if you didn't link the target dll it won't be there.

You really really don't want to load from the current directory; it's quite possibly a place unsafe to load dlls from.

To get your load path:  `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(myclassname).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location)`

Comment: That's what I don't understand... as I'm manually copying the libraries in the execution directory (bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1 or bin\Debug), but still failing to load. Only works when I use the event to use full path of the library explicitly.

About loading from current directory, the app reads some configuration files where types are configured and créate instances of that types. This way I can reuse the app and only develop a particular library for every customer. Any idea of how to improve this?