# Howto use external plugins via config file (runtime configuration) with Unity Container 5

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to setup a simple .NET Core 3.1 project that uses Unity Container 5 [(https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity)](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity).

I've added a reference to latest Unity Configuration 5.11.1 package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Configuration/).

Then I've created interface, implementation and test app with a simplest config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Unity.Configuration" />
  </configSections>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <container>
      <register
        type="Interfaces.InterfaceN, Interfaces"
        mapTo="Implementations.ImplementationN, Implementations">
      </register>
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

But I'm getting **System.InvalidOperationException**:

> {"The type name or alias Implementations.ImplementationN,
> Implementations could not be resolved. Please check your configuration
> file and verify this type name."}

I've uploaded my code to [GitHub](https://github.com/bairog/UnityContainer5Test/).

P.S. Visual Studio 2019 16.4.4 Enterprise, Windows 10 1909 x64 Professional

P.P.S. Same code compiled for .NET Framework 4.8 works fine - [GitHub](https://github.com/bairog/UnityContainer5TestNetFramework)

### Update

To clarify more - I need an approach without ANY project referencing Implementations.dll, I should be able to change specific implementation (via changing config.json) without recompilation.

Comment: A few questions: IDE & Version?  OS?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 16.4.4 Enterprise, Windows 10 1909 x64 Professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out this more a ".NET Core assembly loading" problem than an IoC container problem.

To cut a long story short, if the assembly isn't specifically referenced by your app, you need to tell .NET Core assembly loader where to get it **EVEN IF IT'S IN YOUR BIN FOLDER**.

So if you (like me) don't want to have a bootstrap library that references **all** implementation libraries that you need but you want to have runtime configuration via config file - you should do the following.

From [Autofac IoC](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/blob/master/src/ConfigurationExample/Program.cs) examples repository:

```
// THIS IS THE MAGIC!
// .NET Core assembly loading is confusing. Things that happen to be in your bin folder don't just suddenly
// qualify with the assembly loader. If the assembly isn't specifically referenced by your app, you need to
// tell .NET Core where to get it EVEN IF IT'S IN YOUR BIN FOLDER.
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918837/net-core-1-1-type-gettype-from-external-assembly-returns-null
//
// The documentation says that any .dll in the application base folder should work, but that doesn't seem
// to be entirely true. You always have to set up additional handlers if you AREN'T referencing the plugin assembly.
// https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/corehost.md
//
// To verify, try commenting this out and you'll see that the config system can't load the external plugin type.
var executionFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += (AssemblyLoadContext context, AssemblyName assembly) =>
{
     // DISCLAIMER: NO PROMISES THIS IS SECURE. You may or may not want this strategy. It's up to
     // you to determine if allowing any assembly in the directory to be loaded is acceptable. This
     // is for demo purposes only.
     return context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(Path.Combine(executionFolder, $"{assembly.Name}.dll"));
 };
```

And after that the following code

```
var container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();

var type = container.Resolve<InterfaceN>();
```

is working like a charm.

**P.S.** Some more info from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support)