# Howto use external plugins via config file (runtime configuration) with Autofac 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm trying to setup a simple **.NET Core 3.1** project that uses **Autofac 5** [IoC Container](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac).

I've added a reference to latest **Autofac.Configuration 5.0.0** [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/autofac.Configuration/).

I've created interface, implementation and test app with a simple JSON config (following [this guide](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html#quick-start)):

```
{
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "Implementations.ImplementationN, Implementations",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "Interfaces.InterfaceN, Interfaces"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I use the following code (according to the same guide):

```
using Interfaces;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;

------------------------
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
config.AddJsonFile("config.json");

var module = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();    
builder.RegisterModule(module);

var container = builder.Build();
------------------------
```

But I'm getting **System.InvalidOperationException**:

> The type 'Implementations.ImplementationN, Implementations' 
>   could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, 
>   e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly"

I've uploaded my code to [GitHub](https://github.com/bairog/Autofac5ContainerTest). Any help is appreciated.

**P.S.** Visual Studio 2019 16.4.5 Enterprise, Windows 10 1909 x64 Professional

**UPDATE:** To clarify more - my final goal is to have **Interfaces.dll** with no special references, **Implementations.dll** with reference to ONLY **Interfaces.dll** and **Test.exe** with reference to ONLY **Interfaces.dll** (and Autofac package of course). I expect Autofac to load specific class from a specific assembly (that are specified in **config.json**) via Reflection. That was possible with **Unity Container** and I expected to achieve the same with **Autofac IoC**.

**Once again:** I need an upproach without ANY project referencing Implementations.dll, I should be able to change specific implementation (via changing config.json) without recompilation.

Comment: You never registered the types anywhere and there is no module to load. it's better to load the module by the assembly and put the registration of the types in the separate modules

Comment: Do you mean something like `builder.RegisterType<ImplementationN>().As<InterfaceN>();` ? But library that contains this piece of code (let's name it **fabric library**) should reference **Implementation.dll**, right? When I was using Unity Container **fabric library** should reference only **Interface.dll** - all configuration was is config file. Is it possible with Autofac IoC?

Comment: yes, it is possible to do that. you have to do something like this:
```c#
public class ImplementationModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<ImplementationN>().As<InterfaceN>();
  }
 }
```
ImplementationModule should be in the implementations project. I think the config.json file is not right. see https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules.html#encapsulated-configuration

Comment: But for that aproach **Implementation library** should reference **Aurofac.dll** - when I was using Unity that was not necessary. Ok, I've tried this approach: added **ImplementationModule.cs** to Implementation project and changed config.json to `{
  "modules": [
    {
      "type": "Implementations.ImplementationModule, Implementations"
    }
  ]
}`. Same error - **The type 'Implementations.ImplementationModule, Implementations' could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out this more a ".NET Core assembly loading" problem than an Autofac problem.

To cut a long story short, if the assembly isn't specifically referenced by your app, you need to tell .NET Core assembly loader where to get it **EVEN IF IT'S IN YOUR BIN FOLDER**.

So if you (like me) don't want to have a bootstrap library that references **all** implementation libraries that you need but you want to have runtime configuration via config file - you should do the following.

From [Autofac examples](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/blob/master/src/ConfigurationExample/Program.cs):

```
// THIS IS THE MAGIC!
// .NET Core assembly loading is confusing. Things that happen to be in your bin folder don't just suddenly
// qualify with the assembly loader. If the assembly isn't specifically referenced by your app, you need to
// tell .NET Core where to get it EVEN IF IT'S IN YOUR BIN FOLDER.
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918837/net-core-1-1-type-gettype-from-external-assembly-returns-null
//
// The documentation says that any .dll in the application base folder should work, but that doesn't seem
// to be entirely true. You always have to set up additional handlers if you AREN'T referencing the plugin assembly.
// https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/corehost.md
//
// To verify, try commenting this out and you'll see that the config system can't load the external plugin type.
var executionFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += (AssemblyLoadContext context, AssemblyName assembly) =>
{
     // DISCLAIMER: NO PROMISES THIS IS SECURE. You may or may not want this strategy. It's up to
     // you to determine if allowing any assembly in the directory to be loaded is acceptable. This
     // is for demo purposes only.
     return context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(Path.Combine(executionFolder, $"{assembly.Name}.dll"));
 };
```

And after that the following code:

```
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .AddJsonFile("autofac.json")
     .Build();
 var configModule = new ConfigurationModule(config);
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.RegisterModule(configModule);
 var container = builder.Build();
```

is working like a charm.

**P.S.** Some more info from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the main project is looking for the type you entered to the config.json file but it doesn't have reference to the implementations project so it will not found the module. My solution is, first add a reference to the implementations project then create an autofac module in the implementations project (you need autofac lib in the implementations project so it is better to have a shared kernel or simply shared project for all projects):

```
public class ImplementationModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<ImplementationN>().As<InterfaceN>();
        }
    }
```

All your registration of the implimentation project goes here.
Then change the config.json file like this:

```
{
  "modules": [
    {
      "type": "Implementations.ImplementationModule, Implementations"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then everything should be fine.
If you want don't want your main project to have reference to the implementations project you need to add some new project that to the registration of all the modules of your application. And it should have references to all the projects as well.

Comment: As I wrote above I've tried exactly that code - [GutHub](https://github.com/bairog/Autofac5ContainerTestViaModules) . Same exception untill I add reference to **Implementations.dll** in Test app. But my aim is NOT to have that reference. Updated my question for more info.

Comment: Once again: I need an upproach without ANY project referencing **Implementations.dll**, I should be able to change specific implementation (via changing **config.json**) without recompilation.

Comment: I think you should add some workaround like load assemblies yourself. I have a problem with running your project. let me check again if I could make it work with manually loading assemblies

Comment: What problems do you have with running my project? I've just tried on a separate PC - it compiles and debugs with no problem..

Comment: when I run your project it completes immediately and it shows **Process finished with exit code 0.
** without letting me debug or anything else.

Comment: You have **Test** project set as startup project and you have a breakpoint set inside **Test\Program.cs** file (for example on `var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();`)? Very strange..

Comment: yes, I did. unfortunately, I don't have any solution. I think it's not possible to do so. You need a root project to access all the others to do the registration of the modules and I think it is ok for the main project to have a reference. because just the interfaces are public and the implementations are internal and they are just visible for the project not to the entire projects.

Comment: But this approach doesn't allow me to switch one implementation to enother without recompiling that root project. What what is the use of IoC container if it depends on specific implementation? I can simply reference implementation in my **Test** project and don't use interface resolving by IoC at all.. My current project (targets **.NET Framework 4.0**) succesfully uses that approach (config-only, no recompilation) with **MS Enterprise Library 5 (Unity Container 2)**. Now I'm upgrading to **.NET Core 3.1** and surprised that **Autofac** doesn't support runtime configuration (in config file)..

Comment: You can add multiple implementations for one interface and you can resolve the one you want by tag or name or all of them. I think it is something in your code you should add to get specific implementation in different situations. Like add the name of a specific implementation in the config file and then resolve the object by name.  It will work the way you want. change the implementation without compiling again. https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html