# Resolve dependencies when loading an assembly in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

I have a project in .NET Core and I need to load an *Assembly* (compiled with *Roslyn*) to a sandbox, in order to isolate the code execution.

My first thought was use an *AppDomain*, but it's not possible in .NET Core.

So, the solution is to use *AssemblyLoadContext*.

The following code is my *Assembly Loader*:

```
public class AssemblyContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    public Assembly Load(Stream stream)
    {
        this.Resolving += ResolvingHandler;
        return this.LoadFromStream(stream);
    }

    public Assembly ResolvingHandler(AssemblyLoadContext context, AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        var assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyName(assemblyName);
        Console.WriteLine("Resolving: " + assemblyName.FullName);
        return assembly;
    }
}
```

My problem here is after the load of the *Assembly*, the *Resolving* method is not called and the dependencies are not loaded, making my compiled code not working.

Is necessary to do any additional steps to the *ResolvingHandler* be called?
Or this isn't possible to do in .NET Core?

Comment: I can highly recommend checking out the assembly resolver detailed in this article [Resolving Assemblies in .NET Core](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194332/WebControls/)

Comment: Take a look at this question with lots of answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895278/how-to-load-assemblies-located-in-a-folder-in-net-core-console-app/53282887

Answer (score 5):

As from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.resolving?view=netcore-3.0) it is not called by design:

> **AssemblyLoadContext.Resolving Event**
>
> Occurs when the resolution of an assembly **fails** when attempting to load into this assembly load context.