# Dynamic load and call of C# DotNet DLL from another C# DotNet DLL

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

I don't know if what I want to do is even possible.  I have two C# DotNet DLLs: Parent.DLL and Child.DLL. Both are built with Visual Studio 2010 using .NET Framework 4.

Parent.DLL makes use of routines in Child.DLL. However, at runtime, Parent.DLL and Child.DLL will be in different directories.

Is there a way for Parent.DLL to dynamically load and use Child.DLL at runtime?

I came across [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895278/how-to-load-assemblies-located-in-a-folder-in-net-core-console-app) for use in a console app that is dynamically loading a DotNet DLL and I'm trying to adapt it for use by a DotNet DLL. However, the reference it requires is not recognized when added to the project:

```cs
using System.Runtime.Loader;
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible? Do I need a later version of DotNet?

Comment: Of course it is. Take a look at the `Assembly.Load()` method

Comment: The CLR is already very good at dynamically loading DLLs without any help.  Giving it a hard time to locate such a DLL is a pretty bad idea, you never intentionally want to create DLL Hell.  But you can with the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event.  If you meant to create a plugin architecture (allowing people you don't know to create DLLs) then it becomes a different story, be sure to google those words to find good solutions, prefix "c#".

Answer (score 0):

The phrase you are looking for is reflection. Reflection in the .NET framework allows for dynamically loading in DLL's into the calling assembly assuming they are written in the .NET framework and the methods you are trying to call are public. MSDN has good documentation on it as was already mentioned previously [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load(v=vs.110).aspx).