# How can I dynamically load assemblies referenced by project, but not referenced in code

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

Consider a .NET Core application that references a NuGet package.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyPackage" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

If my code references a type in `MyPackage`, then the `MyPackage` assembly will get loaded. If I print out all the referenced or loaded assemblies then it will appear.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Because I have a reference to a type in MyPackage, the assembly 
    // is loaded and will be printed out by both foreach statements below.
    var throwaway = typeof(MyPackage.Cars);
    foreach (var an in Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies())
    {
        WriteLine(an.Name);
    }

    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
    }
}
```

However, if I get rid of that `throwaway` line, then then assembly is *not* loaded, and so is not available by either `GetReferencedAssemblies` or `GetAssemblies`.

The .NET Framework had this same problem, and the fix was typically to read all the assemblies in the executing folder and load them manually - something like:

```
Directory
    .GetFiles(executingFolder, "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath));
```

However, .NET Core will load assemblies from other places (such as the NuGet cache - I've not found a comprehensive description of the new binding process as of yet), so the above approach won't work.

### Question

So, my question is: How can I dynamically load all DLLs that are referenced by my csproj file (as NuGet PackageReferences). My use-case is fairly esoteric so I don't think any other mechanism will do.

### Background

Ok, so someones going to ask what my use-case is, so here it is.

We have a set of interfaces that define messages (IAuditEvent, IValidationEvent, that sort of thing). We also have various implementations of these interfaces for different serialization formats (Protobuf, XML, JSON, etc). Each of these is a separate NuGet package (MyMessages.Proto, MyMessages.Xml).

We have a factory that will create the appropriate implementation (`factory.Create<IAuditEvent>()`) but it does this using reflection - e.g. the proto factory finds a class that implements `IAuditEvent` but also is a Protobuf generated class. It can't work if the assembly hasn't been loaded in the first place...

Answer (score 3):

Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies doesn't return your assembly because it's really not being referenced. If you take a look at the manifest of the exe file, you won't find the reference, looks like the compiler optimize them.

AppDomain.GetAssemblies returns actually loaded assemblies, consider:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var an in Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies())
    {
        WriteLine(an.Name);
    }

    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
    }

    LoadType();
}

static void LoadType()
{
    typeof(MyPackage.Cars);
}
```

In this case, the result of GetReferencedAssemblies call is always the same, but GetAssemblies result depends on where you put LoadType - before or after you call GetAssemblies.

On the build server, you won't be building the solution but rather publishing it, so scanning for assemblies is only dev time problem. You can add the following in the post-build event or a dev target in the project and use one of the methods Daniel proposed:

dotnet publish "$(ProjectPath)" --no-build -o "$(TargetDir)"

It's far from ideal though, hope you will come up with something better.

Comment: The only other thought I had was a really nasty one. In the NuGet package add a `MyPackage.targets` file with `<Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Shim.cs" />". And then inside Shim.cs there is a private class that just references `typeof(MyPackage.Cars)` or similar to force the assembly linking. It's ugly, but I've tested it, and it *does* work... But I think it might be further from ideal than your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 1):

It really comes down to strategy at this point.  If you find yourself needed an intermediary to reflect and provide types, its a good time to consider an IoC container.

From here you have a few options:

- [Managed Extensability Framework](https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-mef-in-dotnet-core/) to load assemblies.  Mind you that MEF is one way through, its not 2-way DI
- [Autofac plugin system](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html?highlight=dll#using-plugin-assemblies)
- [Native scanning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.loadfromassemblypath?view=netcore-2.2) which I think is what you're close to.  Some example strategies are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895278/how-to-load-assemblies-located-in-a-folder-in-net-core-console-app)

Comment: We have a DI container for loading dependencies that we know about beforehand. However, in this case we don't know what the exact names of the types or assembly are - all we know is that our project is referencing a nuget package that has some DLLs in it. This was easy to find in the full-fat Framework as I described - but I can't see how to do the equivalent for a .NET core application.

Comment: I mean - I could do the native scanning approach (it's broadly what I've described earlier) - but how do I identify which folders to scan? Do I need to parse the Deps.json file and then root around  in the nuget cache at `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`? I feel there must be a better way!!

Comment: There isn’t any good catch all way. This is a problem from the first days of .NET that has never had a perfect solution and it’s harder now because of the nuget package cache. Your best bet is to ensure that the assemblies you want to scan are published to the bin directory of your app (not the package cache) and explicitly load all assemblies in that folder, then search the AppDomain

Comment: Yep - so make it work like the old framework used to then! I suspected that would be the case - I was hoping someone would suggest a magic framework class that would do the nuget download and loading for me...