# How can I load the dependencies of "non referenced" DLLs in a .NET Core 3.1 web app?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

I am porting a ASP.NET MVC 3 project to ASP.NET Core 3.1. I can not find a way to let the runtime load an external assembly. Back in the .NET 4 days, I had this "type finder" which scanned all of the assemblies in the `bin` folder for the type I needed. But now in .NET Core, unless I have added a reference to the assembly in the `.csproj` file, the runtime will always ignore the `.dll`, even though it is in the `bin` folder with other executables:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Mytype.dll, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The reason I cannot add references to the assemblies explicitly is because I am trying to build a module system, and I can not predict which modules will be added in advance.

So my question is: How can I make a "plug and play" solution which dynamically loads the assemblies at runtime?

**Edit:** Actually, it is not my assembly which is not loaded, but rather another assembly which my assembly depends on. My real scenario is: My app is using different file storage locations—lets say Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.—and will fall back to local drive if none of the providers can be created.

In my app, I have an interface like:

```cs
public interface IProvider {
  Save(string fileName, byte[] content);
  Get(fileName);      
}
```

The problem is that, for instance, I built a `DropBoxFileProvider`, which of course depends on the official `Dropbox.Api.dll`. Now, I compiled my `DropBoxFileProvider.dll` and put it to the `bin` folder along with the `Dropbox.Api.dll`. I managed to load the `DropBoxFileProvider.dll` using [a similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58301597/987000), using the `File.ReadAllBytes()` method. But there is no way I can load the dependencies of the assembly like `Dropbox.Api.dll`.

So, my real question is: How can I load the dependencies of my *non referenced* assembly, which I loaded by using the `File.ReadAllBytes()` method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37896162/1273882